# Proton Jumbuck ECU code retention

Tags: obd-ii

Anyone know if it's possible to clear fault codes from a Jumbuck's (my brother's) ECU by disconnecting the battery and if so, how long it needs to be off power.
We've found 2 codes for the O2 sensors, one probably caused by us disconnecting the sensors to clean contacts.
Trouble is, we can't isolate the problem because the OBD II (cheapo) software we have won't allow us to clear codes without shelling out lots of money.
Will

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Tried to disconnect my battery same isue .. no change OBD 11 wifi tool $42

Comment: Do you mean a $42 OBD II tool didn't allow you to clear the codes?  Bummer!! We did solve our problem, ie, put the light out, by paying to have someone clear the codes............... and it cost a lot less than $42.  The codes/light didn't come back.  Turns out one code was from us removing an O2 sensor connection and the other was from the exhaust fitter removing the other O2 sensor connection.  The problem is clearing the codes to prove the fault has gone - or not.